# How to Create Seed list In Exacttarget

Tags: marketing-cloud

How can I Create "Seed list" In Exacttarget and  how to Identify seed list when i am sending Email

Comment: Please see [ask] and [answer] - more details will give you far more chance of getting an answer that deals with your question.

Answer (score 1):

ExactTarget doesn't have a way to create a 'Seed List' per say. You can create a regular list and use it in your email sends. You'll have to do that manually for every email send

For e.g. Create a Seed List with name 'A'.
Now while sending email, select your main list first and also select 'A'

Comment: how to identify the Seed list in regular list

Comment: It's not different from a regular list. You would name it "Seed list" or any name you want any adding it at send time, along with your send list/data extension

Comment: @Data_Kid at send time can i select target list and seed list

Comment: Yes, you can send an email to as many lists as you like

Comment: How many Seed lists do you have ? The email will go to all the  lists that you select while sending email. So you don't need to identify your Seed list separately

Comment: @Maneesh can i enable send to deleiverbility seed list check box  when i send Email to seed list

Comment: @ Maneesh How to Query the FromEmail in Exacttarget